# What is an ohmic conductor?

Tags: electricity, electrical-resistance, conductors

Is it *a conductor whose temperature doesn't change when you increase the current through it*, or *a conductor whose resistance is constant provided its temperature doesn't change*?

I've seen it defined both ways before and am confused.

Comment: where have you seen it defined like this??

Comment: Could you be mixing resistance and conductor?

Answer (score 3):

An ohmic conductor is a conductor that obeys Ohm's law. That's all. Ohm's law are expressed as following:
$$
V = RI
$$

That's simple like that.